# Как не выполнять else когда пишешь конструкцию if - else в одну строчку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть у меня такой код:

```py
a = {item.type: {ite.information if ite.type == item.type else None for ite in items}for item in items}
```

Как мне **не** выполнять **else**?

- Пробовал так: `a = {item.type: {ite.information if ite.type == item.type for ite in items}for item in items}`
- Или так: `a = {item.type: {ite.information if ite.type == item.type else pass for ite in items}for item in items}`

Во всех случаях получал `invalid syntax`

Comment: else pass можно смело выкидывать без последствий

Comment: В первом примере я так и сделал. Получил invalid syntax

Comment: значит проблема не в else, ищите в другом месте

Comment: Приведу пример: a =  1 b = 2 
print('hello' if a < b) - мы получим invalid syntax

Comment: Пример чего? Неправильного использования языка?

Comment: Возможно.Укажите на мою ошибку.

Comment: `{ite.information for ite in items if ite.type == item.type}`

Comment: Всё сработало,благодарю.

Comment: добавьте пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Написать `if` после цикла:

```
a = [i for i in range(1, 101) if i % 2 == 0]
```